# Trigger click and chain the click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I need to emulate auto-click on matching elements (links) but I also wan to add the click behavior logic right there on the same line, is it possible? Something like below `alert("my Click Behavior");`

Instead of the following:

```
jQ('tbody[groupstring^=";#Emergency;#"] a').click(function(){
    jQ(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find('td:contains("Emergency")').each(function(){
        jQ(this).html(jQ(this).html().replace(/Emergency/g,"Urgent")); 
    });
})
```

I want to chain the above click behavior directly to the below:

```
jQ('tbody[groupstring^=";#Emergency;#"] a').each(function(){
    jQ(this).trigger('click').My Click Behavior();
})
```

Comment: @Lajos Arpad see my update to the question

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define a click behavior

```
jQ('tbody[groupstring^=";#Emergency;#"] a').each(function(){
    jQ(this).click(function() {
        //what should happen on click
    });
})
```

This is how you can define the same click behavior for many elements:

```
jQ('tbody[groupstring^=";#Emergency;#"] a').click(function() {
    //what should happen on click
});
```

This is how you trigger a click:

```
$(mySelector).click();
```